# Size of view on device not the same as on storyboard in swift

Tags: ios, swift, frame

A subview I have which is taking up the entire view width and defined on the storyboard has a different size at runtime. The size on the screen does not correlate to the size when `myView.frame.size.width` is called on the view in `viewDidLoad()`. How can I get this size?

Comment: is constraints correct in all positions?

Comment: Yes. It is fixed to all sides with 0 spacing

Comment: if the constraints are set up correctly this really should not happen. can you maybe provide a screenshot showing your constraints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewDidLoad()` does not lay out the views, they only get loaded, if you print out any subview's `superview` you will get `nil`. In `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` your view lays out the subviews with the correct size after `AutoLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when the method `viewDidLoad()` is called, the views are loaded but not laid out. Maybe you should call `myView.frame.size.width` in `viewWillAppear()`

Comment: exactly. But from my experience, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called several times, and `viewWillAppear()` only gets called when the view is about to appear. Both seem valid to me :)

Comment: it is, yeah. but since it's just about printing something out that should not be a problem... :)